# How to unit test .NET api core controller with injected dependencies which also have dependencies with MOQ or Fake?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-webapi

I implemented an api controller that will be used by part of another system, rather than users directly.  However, I want to provide a unit test for it.  I started looking at MOQ and then I realized my particular case is a little more complex.  The code works, but as I said, Im trying to make a test for it, without (ideally) writing any data to the Db.

The structure of the classes look like this

```
api controller
    |__MyCustomClass (injected via startup along with configuration)
            |__UtilityClass (method: ImportSomeDataFromaFolder)
                |__MydataRepositoryClass
                    |__CustomDerivedDbContext
                        (override savechanges etc so as to capture EF errors)
```

Note:
- The return value of the api method is a complex JSON object.
- Id like to have a test that avoids actually writing to the Db
- I am creating a custom DbContext (CustomDerivedContext) and overriding savechanges, so as to capture EF entities that change via in a list, eg. `List<EntityEntry>`
- The method ImportSomeDataFromaFolder, after parsing the data into POCO objects and sending them to the Repository for persisting to the Db, then moves the file to a different folder.  When testing, i'd rather this didnt happen, but rather just load a file to parse.

- There are 3 primary things to test:
  (1) Does the data in the file get loaded into POCO objects
  (2) Do the POCO objects get translated correctly to EF model entities
  (3) Does the api return a JSON object that contains the expected results

Or, am I making things more complicated than what should be done for a unit test.  I want to write a test against the api controller, but its the CustomDerivedDbContext that seems I want to use a fake here, since I could then remove the step that actually calls the underlying DbContext savechanges.

Comment: Sounds like you have tight coupling to implementation concerns that make unit testing your subject in isolation difficult. That should be seen as a code smell and an indication that the current design choice need to be reviewed and refactored where possible. If unit testing the API controller then ideally all you should need is a mock of the explicitly injected abstractions. The API controller need not know anything about the dependencies of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have tight coupling to implementation concerns that make unit testing your subject in isolation difficult.

That should be seen as a code smell and an indication that the current design choice need to be reviewed and refactored where possible.

If unit testing the API controller then ideally all you should need is a mock of the explicitly injected abstractions.

The API controller need not know anything about the dependencies of its dependencies if proper separation of concerns are followed.